# Don´t know how to start proving this formula.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

\begin{equation*}
\int \frac{\cos ^{m}x}{\sin ^{n}x}dx=-\frac{\cos ^{m+1}x}{(n-1)\sin ^{n-1}x}-
\frac{m-n+2}{n-1}\int \frac{\cos ^{m}x}{\sin ^{n-2}x}dx+C,\qquad (n\neq 1).
\end{equation*}

I`d like to know if someone could help me with this exercise. Maybe there´s a hint I don´t see right now.

Comment: What is $\text{sen}\,x$?

Comment: @NotNotLogical It's the Portuguese notation for $\sin x$.

Comment: @AméricoTavares Oh that's interesting. Thanks!

Comment: Why not take the derivative of the RHS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're just asking for a hint I'll get you started.

You will need to use integration by parts, as is the case for most "reduction formulas". In this case, note that $$\int{\frac{\cos x}{\sin^n x}}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{-1}{(n-1)\sin^{n-1}x}$$ So integrate the term $$\frac{\cos x}{\sin^n x}$$ and differentiate the term $$\cos^{m-1}x$$ with integration by parts. (It looks like this will work, but I didn't actually check it myself so let me know if you have trouble).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reduction formula should be like this:
$$
\begin{aligned}
I(m, n) :&=\int \frac{\cos ^{m} x}{\sin ^{n} x} d x \\&=-\frac{1}{n-1} \int \cos ^{m-1} x d\left(\frac{1}{\sin ^{n-1} x}\right) \\
&=-\frac{1}{n-1}\left(\frac{\cos ^{m-1} x}{\sin ^{n-1} x}+\int \frac{(m-1) \cos ^{m-2} x}{\sin ^{n-2} x} d x\right) \\
&=-\frac{\cos^{m-1} x}{(n-1) \sin ^{n-1}x}-\frac{m-1}{n-1} I(m-2, n-2)
\end{aligned}
$$